# how to convert dictionary to data frame in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Input I have:

```
{'A': '1', 'B': '1'}
```

Output I need:

```
+----+----+
|A   |B   |
+----+----+
|   1|   2|
+----+----+
```

Code I have tried is below - which is not working.

```
v = {'A': '1', 'B': '2'}

rdd = sc.parallelize(v.values())

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, list(v.keys()))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an easy way using json parser.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
dict_lst = {'A': '1','B':'2'}

rdd = sc.parallelize([dict_lst])
print(type(rdd))
df = spark.read.json(rdd)

df.show()
```